# difference between two images start positions in html5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeRect(50,50,200,200);
ctx.translate(100,100);
ctx.scale(0.751,0.751);
ctx.translate(-100,-100);
ctx.strokeRect(50,50,200,200);
```

in canvas am drawing a rectangle,scaled and translated rectangle's start position is different from the original.

is there any calcutions to find the difference between the starting position of original rectangle and scaled rectangle.how can i get the difference or start position of scaled rectangle

Comment: multiply the second rectangle with the scale parameters? :) `strokeRect(x * 0.751, y * 0.751, h * 0.751, w * 0.751)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Translations (moves), scales and rotations are all transforms.**

Once you get a few transforms deep, tracking original vs transformed positions with arithmetic gets pretty scary!

Behind the scenes, html canvas uses matrix math to track where your transformed rectangle will be drawn.

You can also use the power of a matrix to track the difference between the top-left of your original rectangle and the top-left of your transformed rectangle.

The matrix is actually an array of 6 numbers.  This is the “identity matrix” which represents one point in original untransformed space.

```
var matrix=[1,0,0,1,0,0];
```

Assume that your original rectangle is positioned at X/Y (in your case 50/50).

```
var x=50;
var y=50;
```

Instead of just ctx.translate(100,100), use this wrapper function to **both translate and matrix track**.

```
function translate(translateByX,translateByY){
    matrix[4] += matrix[0] * translateByX + matrix[2] * translateByY;
    matrix[5] += matrix[1] * translateByX + matrix[3] * translateByY;
    ctx.translate(translateByX,translateByY);
}
```

After you’re back in original space, you have tracked where your transformed rectangle is by using the matrix.

You can get the position of your transformed X/Y (but in original space) like this:

```
function getXY(){
    newX = x * matrix[0] + y * matrix[2] + matrix[4];
    newY = x * matrix[1] + y * matrix[3] + matrix[5];
    return({x:newX,y:newY});
}
```

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yuaMs/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // test values
    // objective: track this point into transformed space
    var x=50;
    var y=50;

    // a transform matrix for point x/y
    var matrix=[1,0,0,1,0,0];

    // draw the first rectangle in blue
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
    ctx.strokeRect(x,y,200,200);

    // do transforms using the wrapped transform functions
    // so the matrix is also tracked
    translate(100,100);
    scale(0.751,0.751);
    translate(-100,-100);


    // draw the second rectangle (now in transformed space)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="green";
    ctx.strokeRect(x,y,200,200);
    ctx.restore();

    // Note: ctx.restore() has un-transformed our space

    // get our original XY which has been transformed using the matrix
    var transformed=getXY();

    // draw a dot at the transformed x/y
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(transformed.x,transformed.y,5,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fill();


    // do the translate
    // but also save the translate in the matrix
    function translate(x,y){
        matrix[4] += matrix[0] * x + matrix[2] * y;
        matrix[5] += matrix[1] * x + matrix[3] * y;
        ctx.translate(x,y);
    }

    // do the scale
    // but also save the scale in the matrix
    function scale(x,y){
        matrix[0] *= x;
        matrix[1] *= x;
        matrix[2] *= y;
        matrix[3] *= y;    
        ctx.scale(x,y);
    }

    // do the rotate
    // but also save the rotate in the matrix
    function rotate(radians){
        var cos = Math.cos(radians);
        var sin = Math.sin(radians);
        var m11 = matrix[0] * cos + matrix[2] * sin;
        var m12 = matrix[1] * cos + matrix[3] * sin;
        var m21 = -matrix[0] * sin + matrix[2] * cos;
        var m22 = -matrix[1] * sin + matrix[3] * cos;
        matrix[0] = m11;
        matrix[1] = m12;
        matrix[2] = m21;
        matrix[3] = m22;   
        ctx.rotate(radians);
    }

    // get the transformed point from the matrix
    function getXY(vertex){
        newX = x * matrix[0] + y * matrix[2] + matrix[4];
        newY = x * matrix[1] + y * matrix[3] + matrix[5];
        return({x:newX,y:newY});
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Blue=drawn in original space</p>
    <p>Green=drawn transformed space</p>
    <p>Red=drawn in original space but tracked with matrix!</p>
    <p id="newXY">Tracked x/y=</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've scaled your canvas, every operation that follows will be scaled, including the transforms.
So your second translate :

```
ctx.translate(-100,-100);
```

is in fact performing a translate by (-75.1, -75.1) in the original coordinate system.